# C + WinAPI: How to switch Between Controls Using Tab Key?

Tags: c, winapi, tabs

I have created a small app in C using WinAPI and I have a small problem. The tab key does not switch between controls.
Should it be automatic? If not, can you tell how to implement it?
I have made an algorithm to switch between edit boxes, here's a stub:

```
case WM_NOTIFY
{
if tab key
{
control_id++;
SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hwnd, control id));
if control_id = max_control_id 
{ control_id = min_control_id; }
```

If there's no simple way, then should I use my algorithm?

P.S.: I tried adding TABSTOP, it does not work. Here are some controls that do not work. I am using VS 2010 Express, Windows 7 64 bit.

```
hwnduser = CreateWindow (TEXT("EDIT"), NULL, 
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP,
220, 80, 80, 20,
hwnd, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL);
hwndpass = CreateWindow (TEXT("EDIT"), NULL, 
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,
220, 130, 80, 20,
hwnd, (HMENU) 4, NULL, NULL);
CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Login"),
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP,
80,200,100,30,
hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Exit"),
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
220,200,100,30,
hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: What happened to the tried-and-true method of setting the tabstop and letting the default wndproc handle it?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams That tried and true method is not working for me. See edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to call [IsDialogMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms909636.aspx)() in your message loop.
See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71450) on how to do this.

Comment: solved my problem too, so +1. btw this also enables arrow keys to move focus between controls. Short version of the article: In your message loop, just after GetMessage(), call IsDialogMessage(), and if that returns true, don't bother to go on to translate and dispatch.

Comment: to be used with `WS_TABSTOP` Window Style.

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your controls the WS_TABSTOP style. The [MSDN has the details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ws_tabstop).

Answer (score 1):

Use **SetFocus(GetNextDlgTabItem(GetParent((HWND)wParam), (HWND)wParam, FALSE));** in the WndProc :

```
LRESULT WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{
      CreateWindow(L"button", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_GROUP, 60, 50, 200, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)101, NULL, NULL);
      CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 60, 72, 200, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)102, NULL, NULL);
      CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 60, 92, 200, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)103, NULL, NULL);
      CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 60, 112, 200, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)104, NULL, NULL);

}
break;

case WM_SETFOCUS:
    SetFocus(GetNextDlgTabItem(GetParent((HWND)wParam), (HWND)wParam, FALSE));

    break;

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```